# SQL Server 2008 r2 Is Filter within a Filter Possible?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Hello StackOverflow Community!

I would like to ask for help with this. You see, I need to get the sum of Beginning Quantity and Transaction Amount of the latest transaction per branch of the Product ID. I don't have any problems with getting the sum, but Im having a hard time filtering the latest transaction per branch (I'm new to SQL Server and have been searching for appropriate solution of queries that I can adapt into this but still can't figure it out).

Here's what my database looks like:

```
ROW_NUM |  Prod_ID | Branch |  Beginning_Amount  | Transaction_Amount | Transaction_Date
1       |  Item1   |   1    |         320        |       1325         | 2014-01-01 10:01:00.000
2       |  Item1   |   1    |        12000       |       1000         | 2013-01-01 10:01:00.000
3       |  Item1   |   2    |          0         |        930         | 2013-01-01 10:01:00.000
4       |  Item2   |   1    |         500        |        650         | 2014-01-01 10:01:00.000
5       |  Item2   |   2    |        1500        |       1200         | 2013-01-01 10:01:00.000
6       |  Item3   |   2    |        9600        |       1000         | 2014-01-01 10:01:00.000
7       |  Item3   |   2    |       160000       |      12300         | 2013-01-01 10:01:00.000
```

If I use Max(Transaction_Date) and Inner Join, only the latest transaction of each Product Id will be retrieved regardless of branch in one query.

```
ROW_NUM |  Prod_ID | Branch |  Beginning_Amount  | Transaction_Amount | Transaction_Date
1       |  Item1   |   1    |         320        |       1325         | 2014-01-01 10:01:00.000
2       |  Item2   |   1    |         500        |        650         | 2014-01-01 10:01:00.000
3       |  Item3   |   2    |        9600        |       1000         | 2014-01-01 10:01:00.000
```

But I need it to be the latest transaction per branch like this one below

```
ROW_NUM |  Prod_ID | Branch |  Beginning_Amount  | Transaction_Amount | Transaction_Date
1       |  Item1   |   1    |         320        |       1325         | 2014-01-01 10:01:00.000
2       |  Item1   |   2    |          0         |        930         | 2013-01-01 10:01:00.000
3       |  Item2   |   1    |         500        |        650         | 2014-01-01 10:01:00.000
4       |  Item2   |   2    |        1500        |       1200         | 2013-01-01 10:01:00.000
6       |  Item3   |   2    |        9600        |       1000         | 2014-01-01 10:01:00.000
```

but I do not have any idea how I can filter latest transaction date per branch.

As of now, these are my codes:

```
Select   inv1.prod_ID,
         inv1.branch,
         inv1.beginning_amount,
         inv1.transaction_amount
         inv2.LatestDate
From     inv_table inv1
      inner join
         (Select prod_ID, branch, MAX(transaction_date) LatestDate
          from inv_table inv2
          group by prod_code, branch) inv2
On       inv1.prod_code = inv2.prod_code and
         inv1.site = inv2.site
Group by inv1.prod_ID,
         inv1.branch,
         inv1.beginning_amount
         inv1.transaction_amount
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
(select *, row_number() over (partition by prod_id, branch order by transaction_date desc) rn
 from inv_table)

 select * from cte
 where rn = 1
```

The `row_number` function will group records for the same `prod_id` and `branch` combination, and then number them in descending order of the `transaction_date`. After that, the latest results for each unique combination are simply the rows corresponding to `rn` = 1.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/DBGJ54661)

Comment: I tried your codes and it worked like a miracle! Thank you so much I really appreciate it